# passing iframe url to next page

Tags: php, javascript, url, iframe

I have an auto generating photo gallery in an iframe that changes catagories of images baised on form selections.  The idea was to find the image they choose by getting the url and to pass that to next page with php.  I can get the url from the iframe but when i try to pass the value to the next page i get about:blank.  It also does it on the same page when i use the alert from the hidden form field value.  i think it is issue with hidden form value.

So if you load the page below an alert from the hidden form value will apear, about blank.  Then i have 2 buttons, 1 that processes the form and shows about:blank on next page; the other gets the url from the function value before assigning the hidden field value(this one is correct value).  The url value never makes it once its assigned to hidden field.  So is this not possible or have i done it wrong?

*update* i figured out that the value gets passed correctly with IE it's just Firefox thats not passing the value to next page for some reason.  Please someone tell me why this is and is there a cross browser solution?

```
index.php
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server">
//this function gets url from iframe on same domain
  function framehref(frame,url){
  if(typeof(frame)=='string'){//find iframe (will not find a frame):
  frame=document.getElementById(frame);
}
  if(frame.tagName=='IFRAME'){//iframe:
  if(url==undefined){ return( frame.contentWindow.document.location );}
  frame.contentWindow.document.location.href=url;
}else{//frame:
  if(url==undefined){ return( frame.document.location );}
  frame.document.location.href=url;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="modify.php" name="step1" border="0"><br/>


<iframe src="http://localhost/iframemain.php/" id="myIframe" name="myIframe"     width="510" height="400"></iframe>



<div id="mydiv"></div>


<input type="submit" value="nextpage!">
<input type="button" value="get url!" onclick="alert (framehref('myIframe'));" >

<script type="text/javascript" runat="server">
var image = document.createElement("input");
image.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
image.setAttribute("name", "url");
image.setAttribute("id","url");
image.setAttribute("value", framehref("myIframe"));
document.getElementById("mydiv").appendChild(image);

alert (document.getElementById("url").value)
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

here is modify.php

```
<?php
$url = $_REQUEST['url'] ;
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$url = $_POST['url'] ;
echo "<b>url:</b> $url"?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot access the url of the iframe if the url is from a different domain than the parent page. Also iframe is not a valid tag inside a form

Comment: Thanks for input, i was unaware of invalid iframe tag inside the form, but after placing iframe outside of form i still get same result.  and YES the iframe url is on same domain.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
if(url==undefined){ return( frame.contentWindow.document.src );}
```

Or basically, trying it with `xxx.document.src` or `xxx.document.location` instead of `location.href`?

Comment: Well i tried to switch with xx.document.src and xxx.document.location and got the same result. It always says about:blank once url value is put into hidden form field. The url extraction function works great, the value is always right untill it's placed into the form. That's what i tried to show in my example. I dont get undefined errors, the value shows about:blank when it should show http:// localhost/iframemain.php or http:// localhost/images/yadayada.jpg whichever page they were viewing in site. Thanks for the input :)